# Show hide divs with the same name

Tags: jquery, html

i have a menu wich is like this:

brand 1

- Serie  1
- Serie 2
- Serie  3

Brand 2

- Serie  1
- Serie 2
- Serie  3

the brand is in a div called catmerk
under that div is an other div with the series  called divserie

so all thedivs with brands have the same name
is it possible with jquery if i click brandname 1 that everything in div catserie under the brand div toggles.
so everything is closed in the beginning if i click a brandname it show the series with that brand so not all series of all brands.
i hope you can understand my weak english.

```
<div id="categorie"><!-- een lijst met categorien -->    
    <div id="catmerk"><a href="#">Brand 1</a><br></div>  
    <div id="catserie">  Serienam1<br>
        Seriename2
        seriename 3
        seriename 4
    </div>
    <div id="catmerk"><a href="#">Brand 2</a><br></div>
    <div id="catserie">  Serienam1<br>
        Seriename2
        seriename 3
        seriename 4
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: can you give an example of the html you are using?

Comment: Show us an example of your html :) Everyone will understand that.

Comment: how can i post a js fiddle? with example code.http://jsfiddle.net/LTURg/

Comment: Some people might prefer you to post a simplified, well formatted version of your code here so they dont have to leave the page.

Comment: i tryd to leave 4 spaces or more before my html code but my html isn't showing

Comment: you can post the relavant pieces and someone else can format it (if needed) but try entering  a new line with your indented code

Comment: <div id="categorie"><!-- een lijst met categorien -->
   <div id="catmerk"><a href="merk.php?id=26">Bette</a><br></div><div id="catserie"><a href="serie.php?id=24"> Bowl</a><br><a href="serie.php?id=25">Aqua</a><br><a href="serie.php?id=46"> Home</a><br><a href="serie.php?id=62"> K.forty</a><br>    </div><div id="catmerk"><a href="merk.php?id=5">Bruynzeel</a><br></div><div id="catserie"><a href="serie.php?id=9"> Faro</a><br>    </div><div id="catmerk"><a href="merk.php?id=27">Burgbad</a><br></div>

Comment: why did you remove the a tags?

Comment: the tags are still there jquery and html ?

Comment: `id` should be unique in a document, you have multiple elements with the same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisrt there is a code issue in your html. ID must be unique whereas class could be repeated:

Your html for categories should be:

```
<div id="categorie">

<!-- een lijst met categorien -->
    <div class="catmerk">
        <a href="merk.php?id=26">Bette</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="catserie">
        <a href="serie.php?id=24"> Bowl</a><br>
        <a href="serie.php?id=25">Aqua</a><br>
        <a href="serie.php?id=46"> Home</a><br>
        <a href="serie.php?id=62"> K.forty</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="catmerk">
        <a href="merk.php?id=5">Bruynzeel</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="catserie">
        <a href="serie.php?id=9"> Faro</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="catmerk">
        <a href="merk.php?id=27">Burgbad</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="catserie">
        <a href="serie.php?id=27"> Bel</a><br>
        <a href="serie.php?id=58"> Crono</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="catmerk">
        <a href="merk.php?id=19">Cleopatra</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="catserie">
        <a href="serie.php?id=11"> Premium Line</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="catmerk">
        <a href="merk.php?id=28">Clou</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="catserie">
        <a href="serie.php?id=26"> First</a><br>
    </div>
```

Now on the javascript part, here is an example, it is not exactly what you want to achieve, but at least it gives an idea of the approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // here the id
  $("#catserie").on("click", function(event){
    // add here any action you need.

     all div here will hide    
     $("#categorie div").hide();

     // here all elements with class .catserie will show
     $(".catserie").show();

  });
});
```

One way is to add another class, for example hide. Having more class on your categories would help

Bette

so you can use the selector ".category" in jQuery like $(".category") select all your categories.

you can add also a class for "filtered", and one to hide the content "hidden" by jQuery

active content:

```
<div class="category catserie filtered">
```

hidden content

```
<div class="category catmerk hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to show/hide categories when clicking on them. You can do this with jqueryui accordion as follows:

```
$("#categorie").accordion();
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/y6Rj8/

Note, I had to incldue jquery, jqueryui, and I also had to adjust the css to set the width of categorie div.

Answer (score 0):

Short and dirty with what you have

```
$(function(){
    $('div#catserie').hide();

    $('#categorie').on('click', '#catmerk', function(){
        $('div#catserie').hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nNZB5/)

Comment: looks good in fiddle but i cant get it to work i used in head.<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$('div#catserie').hide();

$('#categorie').on('click', '#catmerk', function(){
    $('div#catserie').hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
</script>

Comment: @SvenB you need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){})`